# XML-22029: (Error) Cannot transform child 'otherwise' in 'choose'

Tags: xslt, soa, bpel

I am getting below error : XML-22029: (Error) Cannot transform child 'otherwise' in 'choose'.

We are migrating 11g bpel composite to 12c.

The xsl version is 1.0

Sample xsl :

```
<when>

  <element/>

</when>

<otherwise>

    <when>

      <element/>

    </when>

</otherwise>

<otherwise> getting error here

  <when>

    <element/>

  </when>

 </otherwise>
```

Comment: Two otherwise together? The content model allows single one https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:choose.

Comment: Please provide a way to reproduce  the problem, not some made up pseudocode - see: [mcve].